# How to interface html form with rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

Recently I downloaded a html template hoping I might be able to use it with rails. But I am stuck at the form template itself. I know how to use `form_for` and `simple_form_for`. But I don't know how to make a nice UI so is using the template.

A part of the form is

```
<form class="form-signin" action="sessions_path" method="post">
```

But this gives error saying `[GET] "/sessions_path"` routes not found. Why is this happening?

But when I use `form_tag` instead of `form` the `sessions_path` works fine.

I googled this ,couldn't find any related posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because form tag can use the rails route, while in pure html you will not have access to it.

Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag to see what the `form_tag` function actually generates.

In your case it would should probably be:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/sessions" method="post">
```